# Selecionar valor diferente de "X" nome

Tags: query, select, where

Como faço para selecionar numa determinada coluna apenas as classificações diferentes de "X"?

Criei o select abaixo:

```
SELECT top 1000*
  FROM [tabela_clientes] WITH (NOLOCK)
  WHERE STATUS= 'pendente' and status_2= 'pagamento'
  and REGIAO= 'sao paulo' -----------> aqui seria apenas diferente de sao paulo.
```

Na coluna `REGIAO`, quero que retorne apenas os clientes que NÃO são de sao paulo.

Pode me ajudar por favor?

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda Leandro. Deu certo.

Comment: Se uma resposta resolveu o seu problema, marque ela como a solução.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não sei qual a versão do BD usado, pois a pergunta está sem o flag.
Em `Postgres`, pode-se usar o `NOT ILIKE`:

```
SELECT *
FROM   tabela_clientes
WHERE  status ILIKE 'pendente'
AND    status_2 ILIKE 'pagamento'
AND    regiao NOT ILIKE 'sao paulo'
```

Vendo no `SELECT` que coloquei, há o `ILIKE` também (onde pode-se usar também o `LIKE`, sendo a diferença a obrigatoriedade no `LIKE` de estar escrito como deveria estar gravado: *maiúsculo* ou *minúsculo*).

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda William.

Answer (score 4):

É possível utilizando o operador `!=`

```
SELECT top 1000 *
  FROM [tabela_clientes] WITH (NOLOCK)
  WHERE STATUS = 'pendente' and status_2 = 'pagamento'
  and REGIAO != 'sao paulo'
```

ou `<>`

```
SELECT top 1000 *
      FROM [tabela_clientes] WITH (NOLOCK)
      WHERE STATUS = 'pendente' and status_2 = 'pagamento'
      and REGIAO <> 'sao paulo'
```

Principais bancos de dados que suportam ambos `!=` e `<>`:

1. MySQL 5.1
2. PostgreSQL 8.3
3. SQLite
4. Oracle 10g
5. Microsoft SQL Server 2000/2005/2008/2012/2016
6. IBM Informix Dynamic Server 10
7. InterBase / Firebird
8. Apache Derby 10.6
9. Sybase Adaptive Server Enterprise 11.0

Comment: Lembrando que, sempre que possível, normalize o banco de dados e utilize tabelas de domínio, onde os campos de consulta são chave estrangeira na tabela principal. Desta forma as buscas serão mais eficientes, evitando busca por texto.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda Luiz.

Answer (score 2):

O ideal é que você trabalhasse com o id da região 'sao paulo' e não com um codigo texto. Mas basta você utilizar o operador `<>`

```
SELECT top 1000 *
  FROM [tabela_clientes] WITH (NOLOCK)
  WHERE STATUS = 'pendente' and status_2 = 'pagamento'
  and REGIAO <> 'sao paulo'
```